# How to get the related encoding on basis of a Locale in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, locale

I searched a lot, but i do not find any solution.

I have a Language for Example `Locale locale = new Locale("ru","RU");`

And know i want to get the corresponding encoding. In this case `CP1251`

Is there any Framework how does this?

Comment: Locales in Java don't have an associated encoding. I think what you're looking for is per-operating-system information (different operating systems might use different encodings for various languages and it might even differ between versions. For example most Linux distros have switched to using UTF-8 for all locales, unless explicitly configured otherwise). What are you trying to do with this information? Is there some external source that the response must match to be correct? Because I'd just [**always** use UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org).

Comment: Thanks for the advise to use UTF-8, but in my case this doesn't work. I need to add the encoding CP1251 to get it work.

Comment: That still leaves these questions: "What are you trying to do with this information? Is there some external source that the response must match to be correct?" I don't think there's an official lookup table for this anywhere as it depends on many factors. If you know the correct mapping, then your best bet is to write it yourself. Since you mention codepages, Windows *might* make that information available somewhere, but I assume that even there it varies based on various factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69900594/how-to-get-the-related-encoding-on-basis-of-a-locale-in-java#comment123562688_69900594), [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) does not include character encoding as an attribute.

To see all attributes associated with locales, examine the [Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) maintained by the Unicode Consortium. The latest versions of [OpenJDK use the CLDR](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) by default as the source of locale information.

As that same comment suggests, it is generally best to always use [UTF-8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as the character encoding unless you have a very specific reason to use another encoding. Indeed, the next release of Java, Java 18, is switching to using UTF-8 by default across all host platforms. See, [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400).